# change config/database.yml's username to be the same as your OSX user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, homebrew, root

I'm using on online tutorial for homebrew to get Ruby on Rails working 
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan

Toward the end I am told to change config/database.yml's username to be the same as your OSX user account.  I am unclear on how exactly to be accessing this infroamtion, and then even executing it.

I need to update the config/database.yml file to match the database username and password and I'm not sure how to be doing it from the terminal.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`postgresql` requires a **role** and a **password** in database.yml.

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres) tells you how to open `postgresql` console from terminal and create a role.

**Step 1: Enter `postgresql` console from terminal**

```
psql -d postgres -U username
```

**Step 2: Create Role**

```
create role rolename with createdb login password 'password1';
```

Use `rolename` as username and `password1` as password in database.yml.

Comment: Thank you! When I go to use the first command, however, it requires a password understandably.  But when I set up postgresql there is supposedly no password as the default.  I tried just hitting enter, and separately tried my Mac password, neither of which worked.

Comment: I was able to log in that way and reestablish a role and password.  When prompted I entered by password, but received the following messages:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock", "database"=>"myapp_test"}

Comment: are you using postgresql or mysql?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: add your mac username after -U `psql -d postgres -U `